# What is !--variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I looked everywhere but I don't understand it (I don't know why it's so hard to find the meaning of symbols).

```
if (!--var) {
   clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

So the condition of if is NOT, then a decrementing variable and then the Interval is cleared.

I don't understand.

For example, if I have var = 10 then when it reaches 0 it does not go to negative numbers.

Comment: Are you sure the variable is called `var`? `var` is a reserved keyword in JS.

Comment: But you seem to understand what it does? It decrements the variable, and when it is no more truthy after that (i.e. `== 0`), it will stop the interval.

Comment: no, it is not var, I should have used example. @Bergi I know what it does but I don't understand it. I think I got it from Cheruvian's answer though

Comment: THe issue was I didn't know about truthy and falsy. Thanks @Bergi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little confusing but if you break it down it becomes straightforward.

```
!--var
```

is actually

```
! (--var)
```

So decrement var, and if it would evaluate to false, then clear the interval

Comment: Thanks. didn't know about truthy, so know it makes sense.